# python, pandas, How to find connections between each group

Tags: python, networking

I am having troubles to find connections between groups based on the associated data (groupby maybe?) in order to create a network.

For each group, if they have the same element, they are connected.

For example, my data frame is looks like this:

```
group_number    data
1                a
2                a
2                b
2                c
2                a
3                c
4                a
4                c
```

So the out put would be

```
Source_group  Target_group Frequency
2               1           1 (because a-a)
3               2           1 (because c-c)
4               2           2 (because a-a, c-c)
```

Of course `(because...)` will not be in the output, just explanation

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please explain the relationship between the initial dataframe and the output? What should be in the `source`, `target` and `frequency` columns?

Comment: Hello, thank you for checking, I have revised my posts: For each group, if they have the same element, they are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about your problem. You could do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'group_number': [1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4],
            'data': ['a','a','b','c','a','c','a','c']})

# group the data using multiindex and convert it to dictionary
d = defaultdict(dict)
for multiindex, group in df.groupby(['group_number', 'data']):
    d[multiindex[0]][multiindex[1]] = group.data.size

# iterate groups twice to compare every group 
# with every other group
relationships = []
for key, val in d.items():
    for k, v in d.items():
        if key != k:
            # get the references to two compared groups
            current_row_rel = {}
            current_row_rel['Source_group'] = key
            current_row_rel['Target_group'] = k
            # this is important, but at this point 
            # you are basically comparing intersection of two 
            # simple python lists
            current_row_rel['Frequency'] = len(set(val).intersection(v))
            relationships.append(current_row_rel)

# convert the result to pandas DataFrame for further analysis.
df = pd.DataFrame(relationships)
```

I’m sure that this could be done without the need to convert to a list of dictionaries. I find this solution however to be more straightforward.