# Group strings in a pandas dataframe column which share a common parent three or more times

Tags: python

I'm trying to find and group strings in a dataframe column which share a common parent three or more times.

I have two columns taken from a google search. One containing the keyword used in the search, and another containing the domain returned.

If a keyword shares the same domain four times with another keyword, I'd like to group them in a separate column named 'Cluster' and tag them sequentially for each cluster. (Cluster 1, Cluster 2 and so on).

In the example, below news and weather would be clustered together because they share the same url three or more times ([www.bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk))

**Example Dataframe**

```
url                       keyword
www.bbc.co.uk             news
www.bbc.co.uk             news
www.bbc.co.uk             news
www.bbc.co.uk             news
www.ccn.com               news
www.dailymail.com         news
www.googlenews.com        news
www.guardian.co.uk        news
www.thesun.com            news
www.dailymail.com         news
www.weatherchannel.com    weather forecast
www.bbc.co.uk             weather forecast
www.bbc.co.uk             weather forecast
www.bbc.co.uk             weather forecast
www.bbc.co.uk             weather forecast
www.weatheronline.com     weather forecast
www.youtube.com           weather forecast
www.youtube.com           weather forecast
www.weatheronline.com     weather forecast
www.reddit.com/r/weather  weather forecast
www.stopwatchonline       count down time
www.countdownonline.com   count down time
www.youtube.com           count down time
www.clock.com             count down time
```

**Desired Output**

```
Keyword             Cluster
news                Cluster 1
weather forecast    Cluster 1
```

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

```
import pandas as pd

d= {
    'url': ["www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.ccn.com", "www.dailymail.com", "www.googlenews.com", "www.guardian.co.uk", "www.thesun.com", "www.dailymail.com", "www.weatherchannel.com", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.weatheronline.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.weatheronline.com", "www.reddit.com/r/weather", "www.stopwatchonline", "www.countdownonline.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.clock.com", "www.whatisthetimer.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.timerit.net", "www.whatisthetimer.com"],
    'keyword': ["news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer"]}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

I've looked at a lot of solutions, including [python, pandas, How to find connections between each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101662/python-pandas-how-to-find-connections-between-each-group) but I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for you example.  Count the number of occurrences of each url/keyword, keep counts of 3+ and then keep only url which have at least 2 keywords meeting that criteria.

We can then turn each url into a number using `cat.codes`

```
import pandas as pd

d= {
    'url': ["www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.ccn.com", "www.dailymail.com", "www.googlenews.com", "www.guardian.co.uk", "www.thesun.com", "www.dailymail.com", "www.weatherchannel.com", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.weatheronline.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.weatheronline.com", "www.reddit.com/r/weather", "www.stopwatchonline", "www.countdownonline.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.clock.com", "www.whatisthetimer.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.timerit.net", "www.whatisthetimer.com"],
    'keyword': ["news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "news", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "weather forecast", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer", "count down timer"]}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df = df.groupby(['url','keyword']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df = df.loc[df['count'].ge(3)].groupby('url').filter(lambda x: len(x)>=2)
df['cluster'] = 'Cluster ' + (df['url'].astype('category').cat.codes+1).astype(str)
print(df[['keyword','cluster']])
```

Output

```
            keyword    cluster
0              news  Cluster 1
1  weather forecast  Cluster 1
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, it works for the MRE but not on my full dataset unfortunately. I'll check again after some sleep to make sure I'm not missing something. thanks again.